# How to retrieve/display title, units, copyright along with JSON data in Highcharts

Tags: json, highcharts, jsonp, series

I have successfully implemented code for a JSONP request, retrieving data for multiple countries and displaying them as lines in a chart.

However, I would need to get the title, units, copyright etc. from the JSON as well, to be able to display that elements on the graph too.

Now, I wonder how this could be done.

The JSON response could look like this:

```
    [
        [
            "series",
            [
                {
                    "data": [                    
                        [
                            2007,
                            2239300
                        ],
                        [
                            2008,
                            2237490
                        ],
                        [
                            2009,
                            2167070
                        ],
                        [
                            2010,
                            2204450
                        ]
                    ],
                    "name": "France"
                },
                {
                    "data": [                    
                        [
                            2007,
                            2324234
                        ],
                        [
                            2008,
                            3456352
                        ],
                        [
                            2009,
                            1241422
                        ],
                        [
                            2010,
                            4543231
                        ]
                    ],
                    "name": "Germany"
                }
            ]
        ],
        [
            "title",
            {
                "text": "Title here"
            }
        ],
        [
            "yAxis",
            {
                "text": "The units here"
            }
        ]
    ]
```

My client's code would need to be changed then. For the moment it looks like this:

```
    $.getJSON(url, {selectedCountries: "France,Germany,Switzerland", type: "jsonp"})
        .done(function(data)
        {
            options.series = data;

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        })
        .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) 
        {
            var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
            console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
        })
```

And I guess it must turn into something like this:

```
            options.series = data['series']['data'];
            options.title  = data['title'];
```

But that doesn't work. Could anyone give me a hint what I should do? Thanks a lot!

Comment: So you need to prepare correct form in the json (the same as chart configarion, including data), load it and run chart.

Comment: @Sebastian: Thanks. I thought that it would work that way. But what is then the correct json so that Highcharts can run it? The JSON-code above is JSON-correct. And I guess that on the client side I would need to have a different command other than "options.series = data". Could you be more specific? That would really help. Thx a lot!

Comment: By JSON I mean return object with configuration, like { "xAxis":{"title":{"text":"aaa"}},"series":[{"data":[1,2,3]}]}, tehen you can load it and initialise chart in the callback (as you mentioned).

Comment: Thx. But I still don't get it. Your JSON brackets look different from the one I receive from the JSON call... I put up [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/jd41gz1q/1/), which perhaps could help make me understand the issue. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it going finally. One has to pass the JSON as an object (and not an array, and neither as string (so, no quotes like ' or " around the object!). Works like a charm [here on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/jd41gz1q/13/).

Here the code:

```
    $(function () {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'spline',
                marginBottom: 50
            },
            series: [{}]
        };


        data = {
                "title": {
                    "text": "Here goes the title"
                },
                "yAxis": {
                    "title": {
                        "text": "Here go the units"
                    }
                },
                "series": [{
                    "name": "France",
                    "data": [[2006,2189260],[2007,2239300],[2008,2237490],[2009,2167070],[2010,2204450]]
                }]
            };


        options.series  = data["series"];
        options.title  = data["title"];
        options.yAxis  = data["yAxis"];


        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

    });
```

Thanks a lot for Sebastian Bochan's great support!